# Intel hd graphics installer 1.4.0 supports ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics

I want to install intell hd graphics on ubuntu 14.04.  After some  searching i realize that intel end the support for Ubuntu 14.04.

Will intel hd graphics installer 1.4.0 install graphics driver or not on 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe it will install or if so it will not run the way it should on 14.04.

Version 1.4.0 is for ubuntu version 15.10. The version for 14.04 was an older version. However, once the intel guys end support, they usually end the ability to even install the older version.

Support should soon be out for 16.04LTS so you might as well wait until then and install 16.04.